# Error on creating chart [phpexcel]

Tags: phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel and getting below error on creating chart :

Fatal error: Call to a member function cellExists() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/scgcc/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation.php on line 3241

This error is occurring on  $objWorksheet->addChart($chart);

Chart variable return below :

PHPExcel_Chart Object
(
    [_name:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => chart1
    [_worksheet:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 
    [_title:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => PHPExcel_Chart_Title Object
        (
            [_caption:PHPExcel_Chart_Title:private] => Test Stacked Line Chart
            [_layout:PHPExcel_Chart_Title:private] => 
        )

```
[_legend:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => PHPExcel_Chart_Legend Object
    (
        [_position:PHPExcel_Chart_Legend:private] => tr
        [_overlay:PHPExcel_Chart_Legend:private] => 
        [_layout:PHPExcel_Chart_Legend:private] => 
    )

[_xAxisLabel:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 
[_yAxisLabel:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => PHPExcel_Chart_Title Object
    (
        [_caption:PHPExcel_Chart_Title:private] => Value ($k)
        [_layout:PHPExcel_Chart_Title:private] => 
    )

[_plotArea:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea Object
    (
        [_layout:PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea:private] => 
        [_plotSeries:PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries Object
                    (
                        [_plotType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => lineChart
                        [_plotGrouping:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => stacked
                        [_plotDirection:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => 
                        [_plotStyle:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => 
                        [_plotOrder:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 0
                                [1] => 1
                                [2] => 2
                                [3] => 3
                            )

                        [_plotLabel:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => String
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$B$1
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 1
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => String
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$C$1
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 1
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [2] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => String
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$D$1
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 1
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [3] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => String
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$E$1
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 1
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [_plotCategory:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => String
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$A$2:$A$6
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 5
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [_smoothLine:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => 
                        [_plotValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries:private] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Number
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$B$2:$B$6
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 5
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Number
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$C$2:$C$6
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 5
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [2] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Number
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$D$2:$D$6
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 5
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [3] => PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues Object
                                    (
                                        [_dataType:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Number
                                        [_dataSource:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Worksheet!$E$2:$E$6
                                        [_formatCode:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_marker:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 
                                        [_pointCount:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => 5
                                        [_dataValues:PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[_plotVisibleOnly:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 1
[_displayBlanksAs:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 0
[_topLeftCellRef:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => A13
[_topLeftXOffset:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 0
[_topLeftYOffset:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 0
[_bottomRightCellRef:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => H30
[_bottomRightXOffset:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 10
[_bottomRightYOffset:PHPExcel_Chart:private] => 10
```

)

Please reply me, Its very urgent.

Thanks

Comment: I have been resolve issue of error, but not graph not showing any values

Comment: Somewhere among all your cell references, you're referencing a cell that doesn't exist in the PHPExcel model

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I have been resolve this issue. But now chart lines are not appearing, for that you can refer screenshot @ http://uvresins.net/images/xls.png

and my chart variable is same as i am mentioning above. I dont know what i am missing. can you please give me any solution / hints. Please help.

Comment: PLease reply, i am waiting very desperately

Comment: Show the actual chart code that you've written rather than simply the object that's created

Comment: @MarkBaker please reply on below , i have wrote question below. i am waiting. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

My code is below, you can see below i am using key array because i am generating array value from database .

I am showing simplified form of code actually actual code has too many unknown things 4 u . i am generating 5 sheets in a workbook.

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$objWorksheet->fromArray(
Array
(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 12/2011
        [2] => 01/2012
        [3] => 02/2012
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => QATAR
        [1] => 102.77
        [2] => 100
        [3] => 102.13
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => SAUDI ARABIA
        [1] => 102.74
        [2] => 100
        [3] => 98.22
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => KUWAIT
        [1] => 94.82
        [2] => 100
        [3] => 102.28
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => U.A.E.
        [1] => 101.22
        [2] => 100
        [3] => 99.94
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => OMAN
        [1] => 101.73
        [2] => 100
        [3] => 100.42
    )
```

)
);

$dataseriesLabels = (

```
[0] => new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$B$1,null, 1)
[1] => new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$C$1,null, 1)
[2] => new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$D$1,null, 1)
```

);

$xAxisTickValues = (

[0] => new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$6',null,5)
);

$dataSeriesValues = Array
(

```
[0] => new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$2:$B$6',null,5)
[1] => new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$6,null,5)
[2] => new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$D$2:$D$6,null,5)
```

);

$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(

```
PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART,      
PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STACKED,    
range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           
$dataseriesLabels,                              
$xAxisTickValues,                               
$dataSeriesValues
```

);

$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(null, array($series));

$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_TOPRIGHT, null, false);

$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Stacked Line Chart');
$yAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Value ($k)');

$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',       // name
    $title,         // title
    $legend,        // legend
    $plotarea,      // plotArea
    true,           // plotVisibleOnly
    0,              // displayBlanksAs
    null,           // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel     // yAxisLabel
);

$chart->setTopLeftPosition('A7');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('H20');

$objWorksheet->addChart($chart);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);

PLease tell me M i missing anything.....